# EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined

Tags: angular

After upgradidng many depencies on an old angular 2 project, I got the following error in runtime:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50
(anonymous) @ application_ref.js:259
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:242
onInvoke @ ng_zone.js:269
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:241
Zone.run @ zone.js:113
(anonymous) @ zone.js:520
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:275
onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:260
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:274
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:418
zone.js:405Unhandled Promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined
    at ViewWrappedError.set [as message] (errors.js:43)
    at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (zone.js:683)
    at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (errors.js:26)
    at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (errors.js:88)
    at new ViewWrappedError (errors.js:73)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (view.js:650)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.create (view.js:550)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent0.createInternal (component.ngfactory.js:125)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.create (view.js:95)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.create (view.js:547)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (host.ngfactory.js:26)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (view.js:108)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.createHostView (view.js:564)
    at ComponentFactory.create (component_factory.js:226)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (application_ref.js:586) ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined
    at ViewWrappedError.set [as message] (errors.js:43)
    at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (zone.js:683)
    at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (errors.js:26)
    at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (errors.js:88)
    at new ViewWrappedError (errors.js:73)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (view.js:650)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.create (view.js:550)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent0.createInternal (component.ngfactory.js:125)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.create (view.js:95)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.create (view.js:547)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (host.ngfactory.js:26)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (view.js:108)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.createHostView (view.js:564)
    at ComponentFactory.create (component_factory.js:226)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (application_ref.js:586) undefined
consoleError @ zone.js:405
_loop_1 @ zone.js:434
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:438
zone.js:407ZoneAwareError {message: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set prope…p (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:47366:57)", originalStack: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot se… (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:130849:35)", zoneAwareStack: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot se…localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:130849:35) [<root>]", stack: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot se…localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:130849:35) [<root>]", rejection: TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined
    at ViewWrappedError.set [as message] (http……}
```

I tried to search all my app (which contains about 20 components) for `.message` and found only few results I used `this.message` property, which I'm sure the problem not from there.

I tried to remove almost all modules and components one by one, and couldn't find a way to fix it.

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.11-3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.15",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.32",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.0.0",
    "angular2-notifications": "^0.4.47",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "dragula": "^3.7.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16-7",
    "ng2-dnd": "^2.0.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-select": "^1.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.20-4",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

Anyone has any idea how I can locate where this error comes from more efficiently?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247165/angular-2-3-zone-js-0-7-2-some-components-broken

Comment: Nope. but it seem releated. I'l try downgrade the zone js

Comment: I saw this error message recently when working with transclusion. Check for  `templateRef` in your components and `<template>` in html

Comment: Suddenly got this error yesterday, have absolutely no clue what caused it, also went back to zone.js 0.6.26

Comment: I ran into this problem this morning with a similar packages file but downgrading zone didn't immediately fix the problem I was having.  In my case I had set the  `template` property to the url of my template and not the `templateUrl` property. Fixing this problem caused everything to work fine for me with 0.7.2 of zone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a problem of zone.js package which prevents the console from showing the actual error!
try downgrading zone.js:

```
npm install --save zone.js@0.7.4
```

Comment: You just saved me hours. Thank-you!

Comment: It solve my problem too! Thankss!

zonejs was saying that the promise was not handled for EVERY 'then' in the chain. Even I'm having a catch in the end of the chain.