# What is [Exception: ZoneAwareError] occured in Angular2 from Angular-cli?

Tags: javascript, angular, zone.js

$ng serve

And some of the properties in my libraries are changed to [Exception: ZoneAwareError]

What is that mean ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41246184/exception-typeerror-cannot-set-property-message-of-undefined

Comment: You might have an older version of nodejs. Check with `ng v` and upgrade if it's lower then [required](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#prerequisites).